# How to query a ManyToMany Field to contain exactly with a list?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have  a User model as:

```
User:
name
```

and a Room as:

```
Room:
users = ManyToManyField(User, related_name="rooms")
```

Now. I also have:

`user_ids_list = [1,5]` and there is a single room in the database only with these two users.

There is a user instance as:

`user1  = User.objects.get(pk=1)`

So, I can get all the rooms of user1 as:

```
user1.rooms.all()
```

But, I need to find the room which has users with ids `[1,5]`.

I have came across: `user1.rooms.filter(users__id__in=[1,5]).exists()` => `True`
But, `user1.rooms.filter(users__id__in=[1,23]).exists()` => `True` also returning True.

Ok. it's like if any one in the list exists in the room. It is returning True. But if both of the users have no room, then it is returning False. How am I supposed to deal with it?

Comment: Only these users, or there can be more users?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah. there are more users in the user model. But,there is a single room with users `1`, `5`. I need to know if users `1` and `23` have a room. Each room may contain two or more users. But, I need to find the room that has exactly these two users and none other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by first counting the number of `User`s per room that *overlap* with the given list of `user_ids`, and then we check if that number is equal to `2` (or the length of the `user_ids`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

user_ids = [1, 23]

Room.objects.annotate(
    nfilter=Count('users', filter=Q(users__id__in=user_ids))
    nusers=Count('users')
).filter(
    nusers=len(user_ids)
    nfilter=len(user_ids)
)
```

We thus first annotate every `Room` with two extra numbers: the number of users `nusers`, and then the number of *filtered* users, both have to be equal to the number of elements in `user_ids`s, since otherwise either not all users in the list are related to the room, or there are more users in the room.

In case this queryset is not empty (for example `.exists()` returns `True`, then there is such room).

> **Note**: we here make the assumption that `user_ids` is a collection of *distinct* ids. If that is not the case, you first will need to use a uniqness filter.

Comment: Sorry man, I couldn't understand. I'm new to django. What is the second filter doing here? And if the room exists, I also need to get the room.

Comment: @whitehathackersree: it looks if the *number* of users after filtering is 2, and the number of users of the room is `2`. You can obtain the `Room`s (there can in theory be multiple) by iterating over the queryset, or in case you know there is one, use `.get()`.

Comment: Would be happy if you explain what `filter` inside `Count` is doing. And how your code works. I just can't understand the docs. Please.

Comment: And the `Q` class too.

Comment: @whitehathackersree: `Q` does not *do* anything, it is simply a way to encapsulate a **q**uery (well usually more a condition), and the `filter=` is used to only count the `user`s in the `user_ids`.